# Glitch where some applications show white boxes instead of UI elements on Win 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, user-interface

I've been having some issues with a couple of programs where some UI elements are rendered white.

When I hover some of them become visible while they are animating or something like that, as you can see in the "Next >" button below.

Most software work without this issue at all, but some others where this happens are really hard to use. This problem is also not restricted to installers.

System information (from dxdiag, because msinfo32 cannot output them in english):

```
   Operating System: Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit (6.3, Build 9600) (9600.winblue_r9.150322-1500)
           Language: Portuguese (Regional Setting: Portuguese)
System Manufacturer: System manufacturer
       System Model: System Product Name
               BIOS: BIOS Date: 07/06/12 14:34:44 Ver: 43.02
          Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3450 CPU @ 3.10GHz (4 CPUs), ~3.1GHz
             Memory: 16384MB RAM
Available OS Memory: 16280MB RAM
          Page File: 8484MB used, 10228MB available
        Windows Dir: C:\WINDOWS
    DirectX Version: DirectX 11
DX Setup Parameters: Not found
   User DPI Setting: Using System DPI
 System DPI Setting: 96 DPI (100 percent)
    DWM DPI Scaling: Disabled
     DxDiag Version: 6.03.9600.17415 64bit Unicode
```

[image: Composite screenshot]

Any solution?

Comment: Have you checked for updated drivers, especially video drivers?

Comment: @music2myear Yep, I've updated video drivers in the past few days and rebooted after that. The problem still persists, though.

Comment: Have you tried enabling/disabling any/all visual effects? (system > advanced system settings > performance

Comment: @Yorik Tried disabling everything and it didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just checked Windows Update and there were some updates available. Installed them and the problem went away.

The interesting thing is that I already had ran Windows Update and had it install everything that was available, both optional and not optional updates, like a month ago. But it seems it only installed partially, as some of the ones I installed today were older than that.